# Why is this considered stateless?

Tags: stateless, stateful

Been discussing architecture of a new service with a co-worker today and there's a concept I'm having some issues wrapping my head around.

Two question really, first one being whether or not the image example used at https://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/08/24/rest-wheres-my-state/ is still be considered stateful, if we introduce two changes:

```
GET /nextImage?userId // Does NOT update the value of current image

// Updating current image requires setting it explicitly:
PUT /currentImage?value=X // X being the image number
```

If the answer is "No" it might make a bit more sense to me, but let's continue.

The service we are discussing is a word prediction service which has an added functionality of "user dictionary words" - it can predict not only words from a static dictionary in the service, but also words supplied by the user.

**My suggestion to make the service stateless:**

```
GET /predictions?userId=X&text=Y&words=Z
```

`text` being the text the user wrote, `words` being the list of "user dictionary words" and the response being a list of words that fit with the `text` parameter (including those from `words`).

**My co-worker's suggestion:**

Rather than sending `words` in each request, put them in a database (identified by the user ID and manipulated via separate RESTful API) and just send the request:

```
GET /predictions?userId=X&text=Y
```

Supposedly this is also stateless, but I'm not quite sure why - isn't this list of words in the database equivalent to storing the value of `currentImage` and thus stateful?

Comment: If the state of the application (in this case, the user front-end, etc...) is the "state" we're concerned with here, I would consider this question more along the lines of "Is the user's custom list of words application-specific, session-specific, or user-specific"?